# SHA 3 algorithm instead of SHA 1 to signing the Android Apk for both Native & Xamarin

Tags: java, android, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, build.gradle

Is it possible to sign an apk using **SHA-3** algorithm. Now we are using default **SHA-1**, it's auto assigned. Our security team reported an issue regarding this. And suggested to do SHA-3 to override weak hashing creation.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of security issue is reported?

I don't know if there are any SHA-3 algorithm for signing but you can increase security by either using [APK Signature Scheme v2](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#apk_signature_v2) from Android Studio or using Google Play App Signing from Developer Console's App Relases section.